# Ionic library with component templateUrl not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I've Created a Ionic 5 solution and added a Library to my multi-solution project with a component "landing", but when I try and use the templateUrl in my landing.component.ts I get

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load
> landing.component.html

Using template with the html works fine. Any idea why?

Doesn't work at all

```
 templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
```

Works fine

```
template: `
  <p>
    core-LANDING workss!
  </p>`,
```

I've tried using "require('./landing.component.html')" but then my library won't build with exception

> The class 'LandingComponent' is  listed in the declarations of the
> NgModule 'CoreLibModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a
> pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an
> appropriate Angular decorator.

Edit

1. Yes Landing.component.html (templateUrl:) does exist. My library does not compile if it doesn't exist.
2. Structure of solution below.
   [image]

Comment: 1) Does templateUrl exist?
2) can you post the file folder structure of your app?

Comment: @E.Maggini Sure, updated my question above

Comment: Just noticed it is a mono repo. Since it works inline but not from url it almost certainly a path issue. Maybe this gives a clue? https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html

Comment: @E.Maggini tried all of that. I think the problem is me using IONIC 5. There's something funky with implementing a monorepo in IONIC 5 using ng-packager

Comment: "Something funky" is definitely an accurate statement in terms of Ionic and mono repos. :). My own self explorations were only half successful. Here's a couple threads I ran across at the time which may or may not help.  https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/619 and https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2633

Comment: @E.Maggini Finally found the issue. Man that took a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. Man, that's 3 days down the toilet for something simple

*Do not use the `ng-package.json` to build your solution (ie. don't bet on `npm run build` work using the default `ng-package.json`). Add the ngPackage tag to your library `package.json` and include the assets you want to import. Build it using the script command to reference the library `package.json` file specifically. Something to do with having to load the peer dependencies to resolve the paths

Your library library `package.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/package.schema.json",
  "name": "core-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "ngPackage": {
    "dest": "../../dist/core-lib",
    "assets": [
      "src/lib/components/**/*.html",
      "src/lib/components/**/*.css"
    ],
    "lib": {
      "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
    }
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Your base project `package.json` (add this into the scripts tag)

```
"build:coreLib": "ng-packagr -p projects/core-lib/package.json"
```

Then build your library running

> npm run build:coreLib

What an undocumented headache.